# How to work with bitfields longer than 64 bits?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

Question says it all.

If I have this for a 96-bit field:

```
uint32_t flags[3]; //(thanks @jalf!)
```

How do I best go about accessing this, given that my subfields therein may lie over the 32-bit boundaries (eg. a field that runs from bit 29 to 35)?

I need my accesses to be as fast as possible, so I'd rather not iterate over them as 32-bit elements of an array.

Comment: What kind of operations are you looking to perform on the bitfield?

Comment: If you happen to be on a 64bit machine with gcc, clang or so installed you could just use their 128 bit data types, `__uint128_t` or so.

Comment: @JensGustedt I had considered that, but I needed exactly 96 bits for compactness of data and better cache performance (those last 32 bits would just be a waste in the cache).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[This answer is valid for C (and by extension, for C++ as well).]*

The platform-independent way is to apply bit-masks and bit-shifts as appropriate.

So to get your field from 29 to 35 (inclusive):

```
  (flags[1] & 0xF)        << 3
| (flags[0] & 0xE0000000) >> 29  // The bitmask here isn't really needed, but I like symmetry!
```

Obviously, you could write a class/function/macro to automate this.

Comment: I'm still digesting this but it's what I was looking for. Thank you for using my example to provide an answer in code.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing a template function to retrieve an arbitrary range of bits when I realized how much overkill it was. If you write a handful of inline functions, one for each field with the masks and shift counts hardcoded as you have done here, you're done.

Comment: @Mark: If you have a template function, you should post it as answer.  It would certainly be more general than hardcoding the above for each field, and safer than a macro.

Comment: @MarkRansom, thanks for your comment. To both, What's the reasoning behind making these macros, in any case? Is that a throwback from C?

Comment: @NickWiggill, making a macro or a function improves the readability of the code and allows for reuse, while reducing the probability of a bug and enhancing maintainability. A macro removes the overhead of a function call, but an inline function does the same thing while being more type-safe and again easier to read. Your question is tagged both C++ and C, and C doesn't have inline functions.

Comment: @Oli, I was only about 1/3 done writing it from scratch. I haven't needed anything like this for quite some time.

Answer (score 11):

The STL contains a class for dealing with [bitfields of arbitary length](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset.html):

```
#include <bitset>

int main() {
  const bitset<12> mask(2730ul); 
  cout << "mask =      " << mask << endl;

  bitset<12> x;

  cout << "Enter a 12-bit bitset in binary: " << flush;
  if (cin >> x) {
    cout << "x =        " << x << endl;
    cout << "As ulong:  " << x.to_ulong() << endl;
    cout << "And with mask: " << (x & mask) << endl;
    cout << "Or with mask:  " << (x | mask) << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: in C++ development, std::bitset is the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks but no -- I wasn't asking for which data structure to use. I cannot afford std containers when casting hundreds of millions of rays per second.

Comment: @NickWiggill - do you have some reason to believe that using `std::bitset` is slower than the alternative? Consider [this code](http://ideone.com/ft2N6), which compiles to [this assembler](http://ideone.com/Sz6Bx). The `std::bitset` solution has three memory loads, two shifts, one "or" and one "and". The hand-rolled solution has three loads, two shifts, one "or", and two "and"s.

Comment: @Rob Yes, I do, because I've tested it. Stack thrashing and cache performance impact are non-trivial given an application of this profile. Now if people would stop marking the wrong answer up...

Comment: You might want to put that assumption to the test. Modern compilers are very good at piercing the abstraction layer. (BTW, moderns CPU's don't have direct support for bitfields either; like std::containters they're compiled into raw bitfiddling code).

Comment: In fact you use uint32_t flags[3];, std::bitset is struct { uint32_t flags[3]; }, what is the difference do you see?

Answer (score -1):

There's no problem with bitfields going over 64 bits. They can be even much larger than yours!

The trouble I see, is that you are accessing members that cross a 32 bits boundary. This is more of an issue. But to be honest, on 64 bits platforms, if you use `long long` to create your bitfield types, then you only have to be careful on 64 bits boundaries.

If your motivation is to make your accesses "as fast as possible", then think twice before trying to be smarter than the compiler. Nowadays, they can optimize as you're not even aware of. My best recomandation here: keep your code easily readable and understandable.