# Reserve space C

Tags: c

Can you tell me the best way to reserve for example 1000 bits from memory in C?
I'm doing a program and i need to manage flags (values =0 or =1). What is the most efficient way to do that?
I was thinking in reserve the space needed and control the flags (bits) using masks.
Thank you

Comment: Which is more important: minimizing the amount of space this takes up, or minimizing the time it takes to access an individual value?

Comment: I would be surprised if toggling flags would be a bottle neck. Usually its the process that the flags correspond to?

Answer (score 3):

The least amount of memory you can access/address in C is a byte which is of `CHAR_BIT` bits width (which is guranteed to be at least 8 bits long). So, if you are looking for a packed structure you could use `ceil(1000/8)` bytes.

You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c) SO question for bit manipulation details.

Comment: +1:  This solution minimize memory usage.  Since the OP didn't specify what "efficient" means, both this technique and Ouah's answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `bool` type:

```
#include <stdbool.h> // for bool
#include <stdlib.h>  // for malloc

#define N  1000

bool *b = malloc(N * sizeof *b);

// for example to set the 42th element to 1
b[41] = 1;
```

Comment: +1:  This solution minimizes access time.  No need to use `malloc()` though.  It could be a non-heap variable, either local to a function or global.

Answer (score 0):

something like?

```
struct bitf
  {

    unsigned char b:1;
  };
struct bitf[1000];
```

if you won't to use bitmask the max size is the max size of a variable on your computer.
[Error trying to define a 1,024-bit (128 Byte) Bit Field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1590893/1419494)

or for min memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

  struct bitf
  {

    unsigned char a:1;
    unsigned char b:1;
    unsigned char c:1;
    unsigned char d:1;
    unsigned char e:1;
    unsigned char f:1;
    unsigned char g:1;
    unsigned char h:1;

  };

  struct bitf number[125];

  number[100].a = 1;
  number[110].h =1;
  printf("size: %d  a:%d   h:%d\n",sizeof(number), number[100].a ==0, number[110].h ==1);


  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
size: 125  a:0   h:1
```